# How to calculate the adjoint of an operator and its domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A : D(A) \subset L^2(0,1) \to L^2(0, 1)$, 
$$D(A) = \{u \in H^2([0, 1]) : u(0) = u'(1) = 0\}$$
$$Au = u''.$$
Can someone explain how to calculate the adjoint of A, $A^*$, and the domain of $A^*$, $D(A^*)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operator is self-adjoint, i.e. $A^*=A$.

Indeed, consider the "minimal" operator, 
$$A_0u=u'',\ D(A_0) = \{u \in H^2([0, 1]) : u(0) = u(1) = u'(0) = u'(1) = 0\}.$$

Then $A_0^*u=u''$ and $D(A_0^*)=H^2([0, 1])$.

Since $A_0\subset A\subset A_0^*$, we also have $A_0=A_0^{**}\subset A^*\subset A_0^*$, i.e. $A^*$ is a restriction of $A_0^*$, in particular $A^*u=u''$ and $D(A^*)\subseteq H^2([0,1])$.

Let $f\in D(A)$ be arbitrary and let $g\in D(A^*)$. Then using integration by parts
$$\langle Af,g\rangle-\langle f,A^*g\rangle=\int_0^1f''\overline g dx-\int_0^1f\overline g'' dx=\\ 
=f'(1)\overline{g(1)}-f'(0)\overline{g(0)}-f(1)\overline{g'(1)}+f(0)\overline{g'(0)}=\\ 
=-f'(0)\overline{g(0)}-f(1)\overline{g'(1)}.
$$

The latter should be equal to $0$ for arbitrary values of $f'(0),f(1)\in\mathbb C$. Hence $g(0)=g'(1)=0$.

Comment: How do you know that A is self-adjoint? Initially, we dont't know $A^*$ and, consequently, we can't say that $A = A^*$.

Comment: This is what I was going to show. I have added the word "indeed".